# A proof question about symmetric difference (or Boolean sum) $A \Delta B = A \Delta C \implies B = C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider three sets $A,B,C$. Is the following claim right:

> $A \Delta B = A \Delta C \implies B = C$,

where $A\setminus B=\{x: x\in A, x \notin B\}$ and $A\Delta B=(A-B)\cup(B-A)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that following eqution is true

> $$A\Delta B =(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$$.

So by assumption we have

> $$(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)=(A\cup C)-(A\cap C)$$.

Now if the contrary $B\neq C$. Then we have

$$ x\in C \ \ \ s.t \ \ \ x\notin B $$.

If $ x\in A $ then we have $ x\in A\Delta B$ but $ x\notin A\Delta C$

If $ x\notin A $ then we have $ x\in A\Delta C$ but $ x\notin A\Delta B$

So $ A\Delta B\neq A\Delta C$. This contradiction so $ B=C$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't get the steps after the assumption of B not equal to C, can you post further clarification?